# In Perl , How to generate All Possible Patterns ,

Tags: perl, combinations

may i know how to ( in Perl ) ,
generate below All Possible Patterns in a file and on screen output , and each slot in the pattern can be accessed , ?!

many thanks for all ,

input value ,

1 , no. of slots ,

2 , no. of objects ,

for example ,

no. of object = 2 , { a , b } ,

no. of slots = 4 ,

then , output ,

no. of all possible patterns = 2^4 = 16 ,

then ,

row is 16 ,

column is 8 ,

eachSlot[i][j] = allow assign or change its value ,

then , output format look like ,

a a a a

a a a b

a a b a

a a b b

a b a a

a b a b

a b b a

a b b b

b a a a

b a a b

b a b a

b a b b

b b a a

b b a b

b b b a

b b b b

and ,

if see 'a' , then do sth actionX ,

if see 'b' , then do sth actionY ,

many thanks for all the advices and helps ,

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please check out: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 5):

```perl
use Algorithm::Loops qw( NestedLoops );

my @syms = qw( a b );
my $num_slots = 4;

my $iter = NestedLoops([ ( \@syms ) x $num_slots ]);
while ( my @items = $iter->() ) {
   say "@items";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I made [Set::CrossProduct](https://metacpan.org/pod/Set::CrossProduct):

```
use v5.10;

use Set::CrossProduct;

my $set = Set::CrossProduct->new( [ [ qw(a b) ] x 4 ] );

while( my $next = $set->get ) {
    say "@$next";
    }
```

ikegami showed the Algorithm::Loops module, which is also fine to get all the combinations.

Comment: whoa, didn't know `[]x` worked like `()x`

Comment: Neither did I :)